# How to remove event listener if the attached function is a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

example:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i ++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("touchend", f(i));
}

function f(param) {
    return function() {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i ++) {
            a[i].removeEventListener("touchend", f(i));
        }
    }
}
```

It just doesn't work，what should I do?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: keep a ref around: `a[i].addEventListener("touchend", a[i].handler= f(i));` and`a[i].removeEventListener("touchend", a[i].handler);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call `.removeEventListener()` you have to retain a reference to the function.  That means you will have to give the function an identifier that you can then use in both `.addEventListener()` and `.removeEventListener()`.  The symbol can be a local symbol (it doesn't have to be global), but you will need a symbol in order to be able to use it both places.

If you can explain a little more about what you're trying to accomplish with the code you show and where you'd want to use `.removeEventListener()`, we can probably offer a more concrete suggestion on how to change it (I don't follow what you're trying to do with it).

Perhaps something like this:

```
var temp;
for (var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i ++) {
    temp = f(i);
    a[i].touchEndHandler = temp;
    a[i].addEventListener("touchend", temp);
}
```

Then, sometime later, you could do:

```
x.removeEventListener("touchend", x.touchEndHandler);
```

Or, depending upon where your `.removeEventListener()` code is, you might be able to save the function reference in a closure variable.